# How to change the format and style of rss feeds in my slack channel?

Tags: rss, bots, rss-reader, slack-api, slack

now after i integrate my website RSS with slack to display new feeds ,
can i change the way and the format of new feeds that displayed in slack channel? 
 can i make new format or style to dispaly this feeds ?